# How to publish my MVC5 Application into IIS with no error result

Tags: iis, asp.net-mvc-5, publishing

I already published my MVC5 Web application into IIS and my some view are working fine

[image]

but when i open my Contact List View i'm getting error and i also noticed that my default URL is localhost/TBSWeb/MainWeb/MainWeb but when I click Contact List Button TBSWeb has been removed anyone can give me some information about what is my mistake?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that we lost the area property, please pay attention to the code snippets for redirection.
**Backend:**
`return RedirectToAction("action", "controller", new { area = "area" });`

**FrontEnd:**

```
Html.ActionLink("Link Text", "ActionName", "ControllerName", new { Area = "AreaName" }, new{})
```

Alternatively, there are some routing errors during the redirection. Please refer to the below usage of the html helper.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/dn154285(v%3Dvs.118)

Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.